# Bulk import from dbase dbf to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms, dbf, dbase

I have hundreds of .dbf files separated into different folders, basically organized as a bunch of different databases with the same structure. Some extend into the millions of rows. I need that data to end up in a SQL Server database (or multiple databases?), so my team can work with it more easily.

I can't do it manually via Access or the Import/Export Wizard as most tutorials suggest, because there are too many files. I have **Access 2016**, **SSMS 17**, **Visual Studio 2017**, and **Windows 10** 64 bit. I have been able to open individual tables in Access through the *dBase V* setting.

I don't know where to start, because I'm pretty new to everything. For example, should I write a console app, configure some SSMS setting, or do something else I'm unaware of?

Could you outline a high level step-by-step process I should use, and maybe point me to some resources? I've looked at a bunch of docs and forums through Google, but none quite seem to make sense to me. The most promising is [this post](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2463/importing-dbf-files-into-sql-server/), but I don't have the provider listed, like several others in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider **Integration Services** for this kind of import job

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/connection-manager/integration-services-ssis-connections

And here is how to **Connect to a dBASE or Other DBF File**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/connection-manager/connect-to-a-dbase-or-other-dbf-file

Comment: Ok, that looks good. Forgive my ignorance, but how would I use these? Which program do I start poking around in?

Comment: You would need to install SSIS if you haven't originally done so https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/install-integration-services. Once installed you will find way more import/export conversion tools in it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is one time operation you can convert dbf file to sql script and import data into sql server . There are some applications on windows store capable of doing so.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/search/apps?q=dbf+to+sql